# Making ExpressJS app work offline client side

Tags: node.js, express, gatsby

I'm using express.js to build a website,, is there any way to cache the website locally so that if theres no internet it can load up from the cache on client side?

Gatsby has a great way to do this
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/?=offline

Something similar for express?

Comment: Gatsby and ExpressJS do 2 very different things. One is a static website builder (so client side), the other is a  framework for NodeJS (server side). If your website is static, you don't need express. If it's not static, than you can't have the website entirely cached. It depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not about server side

You can make to work client side offline only using PWA caching:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/